# I need to close a form from another form, which did not open the first form. (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I need to close a form from a separate form that did not open said form. If you see what I mean.

So form 1 opens form 2, as well as form 3, form 3 opens form 4, then I need a button on form 4 that closes form 2. How do I do it? I'm pulling my hair out.

form2.close() doesnt work, neither does form2.dispose(). form2.hide() nor form2.visibile = false

I'm pretty new to coding, so I apologise if i'm being a massive noob, but I can't find a simple solution anywhere on the web. I think the problem lies in the fact that the form I am trying to close form 2 *from* didnt open form 2 its self.

Here is the code:

form form 2:

```
Public Class form2

Dim animation As Integer = 150

Private Sub form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    colourfilter2.Visible = True
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If animation = 70 Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.demon1_anim
        animation -= 1
    ElseIf animation = 69 Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.demon1
        animation -= 1
    ...
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

End Sub

End Class
```

And for form 4:

```
Public Class form4

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.visible = False
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.linking, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the form from the `Application.OpenForms` collection:

```
Application.OpenForms("frmOtherForm").Close()
```

A safer way of doing this is

```
Dim otherForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmOtherForm)().FirstOrDefault()
If otherForm IsNot Nothing Then
    otherForm.Close()
End If
```

It is safer, because it uses the type instead of the form's name supplied as string constant (the compiler can check the type name, but not the string constant).
It is also safer because it is checking whether the other form is really open.

---

```
Public Class form4
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Button1.Click

        Dim frm2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2)().FirstOrDefault()
        If frm2 IsNot Nothing Then
            frm2.Close()
        End If
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.linking, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

`Form2.visible = False` is not working, beacause `Form2` is a type, it is not a form object. You need a reference to a form object.

You could also declare a public form variable in a module, that can be accessed from Form4

```
Public frm2 As Form2
```

Then you can create and open Form2 in Form1 like this

```
frm2 = New Form2()
frm2.Show()
```

And close it from Form4 like this

```
frm2.Close()
```

Comment: I must be missing something. It seems that just pasting that into the code under button1_click just comes up with a list of errors. I must warn you, I have very little experience. ;) Where do i put that piece of code?

Comment: Sorry, I was using C#.